# The requested resource is not available when trying to do get

Tags: java, apache, web

I want to make this url to work

```
http://localhost:8080/HomeController/students/getAllStudents
```

And I get this error:

> The requested resource is not available

Here's my code:

```
package controller;
    @Path("/students")
    public class HomeController {

        @Path("/add")
        @POST
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public static String add(Student student) throws Exception {

        @Path("/getAllStudents") 
        @GET 
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) 
        public String getAllStudents() throws Exception {

            return "dasda";
        }

    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>StudentsService</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>
        Jersey REST Service
    </servlet-name>

    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>

    <init-param>

        <param-name>
            com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages
        </param-name>

        <param-value>
            controller
        </param-value>

    </init-param>

    <init-param>

        <param-name>
            com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature
        </param-name>

        <param-value>true</param-value>

    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>

    <url-pattern>/HomeController/*</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

After the first link works, I want that this link work as well.

```
http://localhost:8080/students/getAllStudents
```

Comment: Does your java code compiles? Maybe I'm wrong but a closing brace `}` is missing in java code. The method needs to be closed before the second one starts.

Comment: did you try setting the url-pattern to `/api`?

Comment: Are you missing the context from the URL? Does  http://localhost:8080/StudentsService/api/students/getAllStudents do anything? Or possibly simpler still, http://localhost:8080/StudentsService

Answer (score 0):

```
     @Path("/students")
    public class HomeController {

        @Path("/add")
        @POST
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public static String add(Student student) throws Exception {

        @Path("/getAllStudents") 
        @GET 
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) 
        public String getAllStudents() throws Exception {

            return "dasda";
        }

    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>StudentsService</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>
        Jersey_REST_Service
    </servlet-name>

    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>

    <init-param>

        <param-name>
            com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages
        </param-name>

        <param-value>
            name_of_teh package(e.g. if your HomeController lies in com.urName.controller.HomeController, then value is com.urName.controller)
        </param-value>

    </init-param>

    <init-param>

        <param-name>
            com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature
        </param-name>

        <param-value>true</param-value>

    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-name>Jersey_REST_Service</servlet-name>

    <url-pattern>/HomeController/*</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The @Path should contain never have a slash at end, sine that makes path something like /students//.
Additionally, the Controller package has not been mapped with Jersey packages, where it should find the controllers.
please try the corrected code snippet posted above.

Comment: fixed, still not working, package of  homecontroller is controller

Comment: can you share the jars you are using ?

Comment: can u look in deployement logs, is it throwing error. One possible reason can be, you are using JAX-RS 2.x, where com.sun.jersey package has been replaced with com.jersey